# NoClassDefFoundError on Netbeans but runs on command line

Tags: java, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run a hello world java program on Netbeans but its giving me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I compiled and ran it on Command line and it worked. Then, I went back to Netbeans and I ran it again..this time it worked (because HelloWorld.class file is under the src folder). After deleting the .class file from the folder, it did not run again on Netbeans.

It is something to do with Netbeans but I can't seem to figure out what would fix this issue. I checked under project properties -> Libraries -> and the java platform is set to JDK 1.6

I am using Netbeans 7.0 on Mac.

Please help me out :(

Comment: you should include helloworld.java(src file for helloworld calss) in your project

Comment: Can you describe the structure of the Project Folder, content of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is running .class file not .jar when you run project. Usually it runs .class from build/classes directory. If you provide description of your project structure (or even screenshod) we could tell more. [Here is detailed tutorial how to create and run Hello World app in NetBeans](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I followed all the steps, but the problem still persists. When I build the project It says build successful and it generates a class file. However, when I run the program the I get the same error message as above and the class file just disappears. 

Here is whats happening: (Screenshots)
 (After build): [link](http://i51.tinypic.com/aczqfk.jpg) 
 (After Running the Program): [link](http://i53.tinypic.com/f35a2b.jpg) 

The class file just disappears from the build folder..

Comment: I you are sure that after build you don't run "clea" then this is very strange. Netbeans shouldn't do this. Make sure that another external program don't do this. Maybe insane antivir? You can also try renaming your project without spaces. To be sure please provide here your build.xml and build-impl.xml

Comment: I am sure..after I build the project I see the "build successful message". If I right click on HelloWorldApp.java I get the error message I posted above. If I click on Run menu on Netbeans and choose Run Main Project I get this message:  [link](http://i51.tinypic.com/2gwrxar.jpg)